# Trying to modify partitions in vista

Tags: partitioning

I have my main partition first, and a backup partition second. I want to shrink the backup partition and push it to the end of the drive, so that I can expand my main partition. In XP I could accomplish this with partition magic, not sure how to do it in vista.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a modern Partitioning tool, partition magic 8 is too old to use with Vista.

http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/

Back up your data before you monkey with partitions. : -)

Comment: okay so using this app I shrunk my backup partition and moved it to the end of the drive. I'm left with my main partition and a section of unallocated space. I want to merge the main partition to the unallocated space but I cannot figure out how. I thnik i need to format the unallocated space to NTFS, but it doesn't give me that option. advice?

Comment: If you're doing this from **within** vista it won't work. You'll need to boot up using a CD/DVD. You can't resize a system partition while it's active.

Comment: Paragon user manuals here...http://www.paragon-software.com/downloads/manual.html